# Notification Not received when app closed in Lollipop using GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm new to android. In my app, I didn't receive notification when the app is closed. If it is running it received. I tried all the way but still I didn't get the solution. Please find what I make wrong

Here my code:

Manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.REGISTER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR" />
<permission android:name="com.h2o.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
 android:protectionLevel="signature" />
 <uses-permission android:name="com.h2o.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<receiver
     android:name="com.h2o.ExternalReceiver"
 android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
 <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER" />
    <category android:name="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>


<service
android:name="com.h2o.MessageReceivingService"
android:label="com.h2o.MessageReceivingService" >
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="com.h2o.ExternalReceiver" />
   <category android:name="com.h2o"/>
</intent-filter>
</service>
```

Receiver:

```
public class ExternalReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver { 
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
       ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),MessageReceivingService.class.getName());
       startWakefulService(context,(intent.setComponent(comp)));
       setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
  }
}
```

Service:

```
public class MessageReceivingService extends Service{
private GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
public static SharedPreferences savedValues;

public static void sendToApp(Bundle extras, Context context){
    Intent newIntent = new Intent();
    newIntent.setClass(context, AndroidMobilePushApp.class);
    newIntent.putExtras(extras);
    newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(newIntent);
}

public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    final String preferences = getString(R.string.preferences);
    savedValues = getSharedPreferences(preferences, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(getBaseContext());
    SharedPreferences savedValues = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    if(savedValues.getBoolean(getString(R.string.first_launch), true)){
        register();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = savedValues.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(getString(R.string.first_launch), false);
        editor.commit();
    }
    if(savedValuess.getBoolean(getString(R.string.first_launch), true)){
        // Let AndroidMobilePushApp know we have just initialized and there may be stored messages
        sendToApp(new Bundle(), this);
    }
}

protected static void saveToLog(Bundle extras, Context context){
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=savedValues.edit();
    String numOfMissedMessages = context.getString(R.string.num_of_missed_messages);
    int linesOfMessageCount = 0;
    for(String key : extras.keySet()){
        String line = String.format("%s=%s", key, extras.getString(key));
        editor.putString("MessageLine" + linesOfMessageCount, line);
        linesOfMessageCount++;
    }
    editor.putInt(context.getString(R.string.lines_of_message_count), linesOfMessageCount);
    editor.putInt(context.getString(R.string.lines_of_message_count), linesOfMessageCount);
    editor.putInt(numOfMissedMessages, savedValues.getInt(numOfMissedMessages, 0) + 1);
    editor.commit();
    postNotification(new Intent(context, AndroidMobilePushApp.class), context);
}

protected static void postNotification(Intent intentAction, Context context){
    final NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intentAction, Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL);
    final Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Message Received!")
            .setContentText("")
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .getNotification();

    mNotificationManager.notify(R.string.notification_number, notification);
}

private void register() {
    new AsyncTask(){
        protected Object doInBackground(final Object... params) {
            String token;
            try {
                token = gcm.register(getString(R.string.project_number));
                Log.i("registrationId", token);
            } 
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.i("Registration Error", e.getMessage());
            }
            return true;
        }
    }.execute(null, null, null);
}

public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you create service .??

Comment: Yeah, I created service

Comment: can you share code

Comment: Check it now...

Comment: where is push notification listener???

Comment: push notification listener? I didn't knowledge about that

Answer (score 1):

To be able to receive notifications when your application is closed, you have to register a service listener with the following permission

```
android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE"
```

See the documentation for more details

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html

Answer (score 1):

you need to define your broadcast receiver in manifest like this:

```
<receiver
android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
<intent-filter>
    <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <category android:name="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app" />
</intent-filter>
```

and in the broadcast receiver class add the following codes:

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            GcmIntentService.class.getName());
    // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}}
```

there is some problem with wakeful broadcast receiver, read this
[Confusion about WakefulBroadcastReceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32437434/confusion-about-wakefulbroadcastreceiver)

For best practice it is recommended that you should use Firebase cloud messaging (FCM) instead of GCM.