# Android Widget button service does not respond to click

Tags: android, android-widget, jobintentservice

*Similar questions: [service not starting on oreo in app widgetusing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48130247/service-not-starting-on-oreo-in-app-widget-using-pendingintent) The closest to my question is [Widget freezes after some time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29598491/widget-stops-responding-to-clicks-widget-freezes) but is unanswered.*

I have **a simple widget button that should send a notification** when pressed. It doesn't work when:

1. I **clear the app from recents** just after opening the app on install
2. **randomly** stops working sometimes (sometimes all the clicks are triggered together after I open the app again leading to a bunch of notifications getting fired together.)

From what all I have read so far, it looks to me as if the PendingIntent is getting cleared.

The code is mostly taken from the [official app widget guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets?hl=ru) except for starting a Service instead of Activity.

**WidgetProvider**:

```
public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, WidgetService.class);
            myIntent .setAction("SOME_UNIQUE_ACTION");
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getForegroundService(context, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button, pendingIntent);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        }
    }
}
```

**WidgetService**:

```
public class WidgetService extends JobIntentService {

    public WidgetService() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleWork(@Nullable Intent i) {
        Utils.sendNotification(); // this method works and is tested
    }
}
```

I tried both answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48130247/service-not-starting-on-oreo-in-app-widget-using-pendingintent), Broadcast method didn't work and looked indirect as well, so I added `#onCreate` implementation to call startForeground, which didn't work either.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Utils.sendNotification();
        try {
            startForeground(1, notification);
        } catch (Error e) {
            Log.i(TAG, e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

**How do I get a button that will start a service reliably every time?** Any help appreciated.

Comment: Stop clearing the app from the overview screen. On some devices, that will indeed cancel your outstanding `PendingIntent` objects, and there is nothing that you can do about that. In addition, `JobIntentService` is not designed to be used this way -- I am surprised that it works at all, particularly on Android 8.0 and higher. Use a regular `Service`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Is there any way I can reset it? Is it possible to somehow listen to a system broadcast sent after clearing the app and then calling `onUpdate()` to reset the PendingIntent? Thanks for pointing out about `JobIntentService`.

Comment: Not really. On some devices, the manufacturer has decided to have clearing the app do the equivalent of a "Force Stop" from your app's screen in the Settings app. When that happens, nothing of your app will run again, until some explicit `Intent` is used to start one of your components. Typically, this will be the user navigating to your app from the launcher.

Comment: Can this be done at least for Android One phones?

Comment: Well, I would start by replacing the `JobIntentService` with a `Service`, and see if things improve. `JobIntentService`, on Android 8.0 and higher, really schedules a job with `JobScheduler`, rather than doing the work directly. It may be that you are seeing jobs getting canceled, and the task getting cleared is not doing a full "Force Stop". In that case, you may have better luck with a regular `Service`.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks a lot! You were right. A `Service` instead of `JobIntentService` should be used in case of widgets to execute small widget tasks quickly. I am not sure if I can do without a foreground Service because there appears to be a restriction on starting a service from background if the app has not been active. I didn't try it out either as I think a Foreground service is more reliable for my case.

Comment: "there appears to be a restriction on starting a service from background if the app has not been active" -- you have a short window of time to be able to run in the background. If you use a `getService()` `PendingIntent`, it should be one minute. But, I am glad that you are having better luck with a regular `Service`. `JobIntentService` is mostly (if not exclusively) for cases where you cause it to run yourself, via an `enqueueWork()` call, not for where something else will try to run it just via an `Intent`.